# how to get option title="sample" using jquery

Tags: jquery, select, attr

I'm trying to update a hidden field based on the a title attribute on a select option, I've tried the code bellow and can't seem to get it to work.

```
<form>
    <select id="selectbox">
        <option name="test" value="one" title="title" selected="selected">one</option>
        <option name="test2" value="two" title="title2">two</option>
    </select>
</form>
<input id="update" type="hidden" value="defaultold" />

<script>
    $('#update').val('default');
    $('#selectbox').change(function() {
        $('#update').val($(this).attr("title"));
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Encapsulate that code within a `$(document).ready(...` block, and you need to use the *option's* title:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#update').val('default');   
    $('#selectbox').change(function() {
         $('#update').val($(this).find("option:selected").attr("title"));
    });
});
```

`$(this)` refers to the context of the select element, you can use [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to get the descendant of interest which in this case is the selected option.

Answer (score 2):

Accessing the text of selected option using jquery:

```
var title = $( "#myselectId option:selected" ).text();
```